# Field comparison in excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, compare

I have an excel sheet with two columns.

```
Eg.
----------------------
A            B      outputColumn C
----------------------
xxyy
dd/mm/yy     xxyy       Y
----------------------
NA          #N/A      Y
----------------------
xxyy          xxyy      Y
dd/mm/yy
----------------------
xxyy          #N/A      N
dd/mm/yy
----------------------
.
.
.
```

I want column outputColumn-C which checks if both entries are same or not.
here "NA" should match "#N/A" and "xxyy" should match "xxyy dd/mm/yy"

How how can I do this?

Comment: I don't think I understand - how do you define "Match"? Is it a match when one column is a sub-string of the other one?

Answer (score 1):

=IF(ISERROR(IF(FIND(B1,A1)>0,"Y","N")),"N","Y")

Comment: Note that xxyy will match "xxyy dd/mm/yy" but also "dd/mm/yy ZZxxyyZZ"